# Java - Print strings showing newline characters

Tags: java, string, printing, console

I wish to print out strings to the console and it is important to see the exact string meaning that it should show the newline character `\n` in the logs.  So it will be `"this is the exact sequence of chars \n"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace all occurrences of the `\n` character with `\\n` (which will appear as `\n` when printed). You should also replace occurrences of the `\r` character with `\\r` in case it is present.

```
String str = "this is the exact sequence of chars \n";
str = str.replace("\n", "\\n");
str = str.replace("\r", "\\r");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Why `String.valueOf('\n')`, rather than simply `"\n"`?